# which framework to make this simple birthday lookup script

Tags: database, html, forms

I have a table that has a corresponding value for each birthday - all 366 of them when Feb 29th Included.  I need to make a webpage with a script that has a date field picker where it opens a result page from that date for the corresponding value.  What is the easiest framework to accomplish this...I have almost zero php and js experience but feel like that may be what is necessary to build it.  Any suggestions?  The attached code is a very very preliminary bare bones shell page for this frontend, but I don't know where to go from here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
* { 
padding: 0; 
margin: 0; 
} 
body { 
background-color: black; 
font-size: 12pt; 
font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; 
font-weight: bold; 
color: #fff; 
vertical-align: top;
text-align: center;
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
} 
h1, h2, h3{ 
text-align: center; 
font-weight: bold; 
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; 
} 
img { 
border-style: none; 
background-color: transparent; 
}
</style>

<body>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  What is your Birthday?: <input type="date" name="bday">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: thing is...this isnt even my problem anymore - i've been made this: http://natalcode.com :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably will need both PHP and Javascript. Unfortunately stackoverflow is not a tutorial site, so you will have to start learning both languages yourself at least upto the level where you are able to do what you want to do. http://www.w3schools.com/js/ and http://www.w3schools.com/php/ are good starting points.

Comment: Ok I knew I need them but why - like what will the php do and js do?

Comment: I stronly advise you to use a js library like jquery. It will make things much easier than plain js. You will need js/jquery to turn the result from the datepicker into an ajax call to a php page. The php page will query your database table and return the result to the jquery ajax call. jQuery will in turn show that result on your web page.